# Send template to grandchild component (nested template)

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

There is this `TablePackage` component that we use in our project. I saw that to customize how values in a column render, one can pass template named with the specific column name (in this example `status`) and use slot prop `row`.

```html
<!--Code Snippet 1-->
<!--In each row of status columns, we will see status buttons instead of plain status text-->
<TablePackage>
  <template #status="{ row }">
    <button>{{ row.status }}</button> 
  </template>
</TablePackage>
```

Now there are two more components, `Parent` and `Dialogue`.
`Parent` uses `Dialogue`, `Dialogue` uses `TablePackage`.

Parent component

```html
<Dialogue title="dialogueTitle">
</Dialogue>
```

Dialogue component

```html
 {{ title }}
 <TablePackage rows="rowList" columns="columnObj">
 </TablePackage>
```

Now I want to be able to custom render values in a column as in 'Code Snippet 1' which means I want to render a button not a text in 'status' column. How can I achieve this from `Parent` component level? I tried nested template but it was not allowed. With the constraint that I can edit `Parent` and `Dialogue` components but not `TablePackage`, what's the recommended away to achieve this?

Comment: And what about slots in your component Dialogue and TablePackage ? You can then nest your under component by calling them as you want and specify when to use a button or a span with a component tag ?

Comment: @Sayf-Eddine That's possible. But I wanted to use this `Dialogue` component to reuse its other features if it is possible.